# Adding text to a dxf file

Tags: autocad, dxf

I'm trying to add a label to my dxf file using TEXT entity, the problem is that I'm not able to change text style (group 7) and thickness (group 39) ;it always appears in the standard style and thickness.
When I try to use AcdbText entity my file doesn't open at all in Autocad 2015.
My dxf file:

```
0
SECTION
  2
HEADER
  9
$ACADVER
  1
AC1009
  9
$CECOLOR
 62
   256
  9
$CELTYPE
  6
DUPLAN
  9
$CLAYER
  8
0
  9
$ELEVATION
 40
0.000
  9
$EXTMAX
 10
636293.769999
 20
505977.195001
  9
$EXTMIN
 10
636165.769999
 20
505769.195001
  9
$INSBASE
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 30
0.0
  9
$LIMCHECK
 70
     1
  9
$LIMMAX
 10
636293.769999
 20
505977.195001
  9
$LIMMIN
 10
636165.769999
 20
505769.195001
  9
$LUNITS
 70
     2
  9
$LUPREC
 70
     2
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
TABLES
  0
TABLE
  2
STYLE
 70
     1
  0
STYLE
  2
ROMANS
 70
     0
 40
0.000
 41
1.000
 50
0.000
 71
     0
 42
1.000
  3
xxx.txt
  4
yyy.txt
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
LTYPE
 70
     1
  0
LTYPE
  2
CONTINUE
 70
     0
  3

 72
    65
 73
     0
 40
0.000
  0
ENDTAB
  0
TABLE
  2
LAYER
 70
     2
  0
LAYER
  2
LAYERX
 70
     0
 62
   131
  6
CONTINUE
  0
ENDTAB
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
POLYLINE
  8
LAYERX
 66
     1
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 70
     9
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636166
 20
505769
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636294
 20
505769
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636294
 20
505977
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636166
 20
505977
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636166
 20
505769
 70
    32
  0
SEQEND
  0
POLYLINE
  8
LAYERX
 66
     1
 10
0.0
 20
0.0
 70
     9
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636234
 20
505904
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636255
 20
505890
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636232
 20
505866
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636205
 20
505843
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636209
 20
505880
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636212
 20
505885
 70
    32
  0
VERTEX
  8
LAYERX
 10
636234
 20
505904
 70
    32
  0
SEQEND
  0
TEXT
  8
label
 39
20
 10
636212
 20
505885
 40
9.28
 41
1
  1
Label
  7
ROMANS
  0
ENDSEC
  0
EOF
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your **style** entry is incomplete in the DXF file for **ROMANS**.

It should be:

```
  0
STYLE
  2
ROMANS
 70
     0
 40
0.0
 41
1.0
 50
0.0
 71
     0
 42
2.5
  3
romans.shx
  4

  0
```

Here is the details about the **STYLE** entry:

[image: Style properties]

Comment: Also, your example has "EOF  " for the last line. Try removing the trailing white space.

Answer (score 0):

For the text thickness you use **group code 370**.

it is given in mm * 100, like in this dxf file:

```
  0
SECTION
  2
TABLES
  0
TABLE
  2
LAYER
  0
LAYER
  2
RedLayer
 62
1
999
### Group code 62 Color
  0
ENDTAB
  0
ENDSEC
  0
SECTION
  2
ENTITIES
  0
TEXT
  1
thick 1.22 mm, height 14 mm, color red
  8
RedLayer
 10
12
 20
12
 40
14.0
 41
1
370
 122
999 
### Group code 10, 20, 30 insertion point, 40 height, 1 text value, 50 rotation angle
999 
### 41 X-scale factor, 51 oblique angle, 7 text style name, 71 text generation flags
999 
### 72 horizontal justification type, 73 vertical justification type, 11, 21, 31 alignment point
999 
### Group code: 8 is Layer for the color
999 
### Group code: 370 is text thickness value 211 => 2,11 mm
  0
ENDSEC
  0
EOF
```